# How to save best weights of the encoder part only during auto-encoder training??

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, autoencoder

I am using keras with tensor flow to implement a deep auto-encoder with CNN:

So basically the model would be similar to:

```
    input_data = Input(shape=(40,500,1))

    #encoder  
    x= Conv2D(32,kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same",activation='linear')(input_data)       
    encoded= Conv2D(15,kernel_size=(1,2), strides=(1,2), padding="same",activation='linear')(x)  


    #decoder             
    x= Conv2DTranspose(15,kernel_size=(1,2), padding="same",activation='linear')(encoded)        
    x= Conv2DTranspose(32,kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same",activation='linear')(x)
    decoded = Conv2DTranspose(1, (3, 3), activation=activationfuntion, padding="same")(x)

    autoencoder = Model(inputs=input_data,outputs=decoded)
    encoder = Model(inputs=input_data,outputs=encoded)
```

In order to save the best model weights during training, I am using ModelCheckpoint:

```
        autoencoder.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='rmsprop');

        checkpoint=ModelCheckpoint('bestweight.best.hdf5',monitor='val_loss',verbose=1,save_best_only=True,mode='min');   
        callbacks_list=[checkpoint]

        history_info =autoencoder.fit(x_train, x_train,
                        batch_size=batch_size,
                        epochs=50,
                        validation_data=(x_validation,x_validation),
                        callbacks=callbacks_list,
                        shuffle=True)
```

and then later to test on the testdataset:

```
 autoencoder.load_weights('bestweight.best.hdf5');
 autoencoder.predict(test_data);
```

My question is:

I know how to save the best weights of the whole auto-encoder, but is there a way to just save the best training weights of the **encoder** part so I can use it later for testing.
so I can use it in this way:

```
 encoder.load_weights('encoderbestweight.best.hdf5');
 encoder.predict(test_data);
```

Answer (score 5):

Before trying to answer your question, I would like to make a quick remark about your use of the ModelCheckpoint callback. Let's have a look at the default parameters :

```
keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_loss', verbose=0, save_best_only=False, save_weights_only=False, mode='auto', period=1)
```

The *save_weights_only* parameter's default value is *False* which means what you are actually saving is not only the model's weights but the entire architecture ! Thus, when loading the weights of your model you can either redefine the model and use *load_weights*. Or you can directly load your model from the file, using the *load_model* function.

---

Now, to save only the encoder, I would write a new checkpoint callback, like this  :

```
class CustomCheckpoint(Callback):

def __init__(self, filepath, encoder):
    self.monitor = 'val_loss'
    self.monitor_op = np.less
    self.best = np.Inf

    self.filepath = filepath
    self.encoder = encoder

def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
    current = logs.get(self.monitor)
    if self.monitor_op(current, self.best):
        self.best = current
        # self.encoder.save_weights(self.filepath, overwrite=True)
        self.encoder.save(self.filepath, overwrite=True) # Whichever you prefer
```

---

As an alternative, since you already have the save file for the entire network, you can separate your encoder from the decoder like this :

```
from keras.models import load_model
autoencoder = load_model("path_to_file")
encoder = Model(autoencoder.layers[0].input, autoencoder.layers[1].output)
```

Answer (score 0):

The encoder part is the first two layers. So after "autoencoder.fit()" try this

`encoder = Model(input_data, autoencoder.layers[2].output)`

for more "https://www.kaggle.com/marlesson/autoencoder-embedding-for-food"

Comment: Whilst this question has no accepted answer, it was asked 2.5 years ago and has 2 submitted answers.

Comment: I didn't see when it was asked. So, posted this probable answer.